# How to display data labels outside in pie chart with lines in ionic

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, charts, ionic2, chart.js

I am working on charts where I want to create a pie chart same as image displayed below. I got some examples using chart.js, but it is not working as the image where **I want to display data labels outside chart with lines indicating the portion for data labels**.

**home.ts**

```
this.doughnutChart = new Chart(this.doughnutCanvas.nativeElement, {

                 type: 'doughnut',
                 data: {
                     labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
                     datasets: [{
                         label: '# of Votes',
                         data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
                         backgroundColor: [
                             'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                             'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                             'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                             'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                             'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                             'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
                         ],
                         hoverBackgroundColor: [
                             "#FF6384",
                             "#36A2EB",
                             "#FFCE56",
                             "#FF6384",
                             "#36A2EB",
                             "#FFCE56"
                         ]
                     }]
                 }

             });
```

**home.html**

```
<ion-card>
    <ion-card-header>
      Doughnut Chart
    </ion-card-header>
    <ion-card-content>
      <canvas #doughnutCanvas></canvas>
    </ion-card-content>
  </ion-card>
```

**what i want it to look like**

[image]

**what it is look like using chart.js**

[image]

so can anyone help me to solve this?

Answer (score 3):

You have to write a plugin to do it.
In `afterDraw` hook, you have to iterate over Chart Elements and calculate 3 points:

1. Point1: center point of current Arc
2. Point2: created by connecting the chart's center and `Point1`, have length = radius + X (x > 0 will give a better visual)
3. Point3: created by connecting `Point2` with chart's edge (left/right) based on `Point2.x`

Draw 2 lines to connect Point1 with Point2, and Point2 with Point3 will give you this chart:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJprK.jpg

Sample code for chartjs 2.9.4:

```js
const DoughnutLabelPlugin = {
    afterDraw: (chart) => {
      const ctx = chart.chart.ctx;
      ctx.save();
      ctx.font = "10px 'Averta Std CY'";
      const chartCenterPoint = {
        x:
          (chart.chartArea.right - chart.chartArea.left) / 2 +
          chart.chartArea.left,
        y:
          (chart.chartArea.bottom - chart.chartArea.top) / 2 +
          chart.chartArea.top
      };
      chart.config.data.labels.forEach((label, i) => {
        const meta = chart.getDatasetMeta(0);
        const arc = meta.data[i];
        const dataset = chart.config.data.datasets[0];

        // Prepare data to draw
        // important point 1
        const centerPoint = arc.getCenterPoint();
        const model = arc._model;
        let color = model.borderColor;
        let labelColor = model.borderColor;
        if (dataset.polyline && dataset.polyline.color) {
          color = dataset.polyline.color;
        }

        if (dataset.polyline && dataset.polyline.labelColor) {
          labelColor = dataset.polyline.labelColor;
        }

        const angle = Math.atan2(
          centerPoint.y - chartCenterPoint.y,
          centerPoint.x - chartCenterPoint.x
        );
        // important point 2
        const point2X =
          chartCenterPoint.x + Math.cos(angle) * (model.outerRadius + 20);
        let point2Y =
          chartCenterPoint.y + Math.sin(angle) * (model.outerRadius + 20);

        let value = dataset.data[i];
        if (dataset.polyline && dataset.polyline.formatter) {
          value = dataset.polyline.formatter(value);
        }
        let edgePointX = point2X < chartCenterPoint.x ? 10 : chart.width - 10;

        //DRAW CODE
        // first line: connect between arc's center point and outside point
        ctx.strokeStyle = color;
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(centerPoint.x, centerPoint.y);
        ctx.lineTo(point2X, point2Y);
        ctx.stroke();
        // second line: connect between outside point and chart's edge
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(point2X, point2Y);
        ctx.lineTo(edgePointX, point2Y);
        ctx.stroke();
        //fill custom label
        const labelAlignStyle =
          edgePointX < chartCenterPoint.x ? "left" : "right";
        const labelX = edgePointX;
        const labelY = point2Y;
        ctx.textAlign = labelAlignStyle;
        ctx.textBaseline = "bottom";

        ctx.fillStyle = labelColor;
        ctx.fillText(value, labelX, labelY);
      });
      ctx.restore();
    }
  }
```

- Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/wispy-bash-nt7ty?file=/src/Chart.js
- For draw a line with hand-drawn style, I recommend to use https://roughjs.com

Comment: Thank you for this. please find working version for chart js v3 [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-dubinsky-jgx8n?file=/src/Chart.js)

Answer (score 2):

For having this outlet you must add the following plugin to your project:

**chartjs-plugin-piechart-outlabels**

[Read the documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chartjs-plugin-piechart-outlabels)

Answer (score -1):

The problem with the style is `type: 'doughnut'`. This will display a doughnut style chart, if you want the pie style you should use `type: 'pie'`

For more info: http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/doughnut.html

Also, about the data labels, I don't think that style is currently supported by chartJs, you can try to customize it: http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/tooltip.html#tooltip-configuration

Or try some options.. https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-plugin-datalabels

Comment: i dont want the pie style ,  i want to display data labels outside chart with lines indicating the data labels

Comment: Yes, thats why I put some links with options there.
You can try to customize the data labels with the tooltip configuration, add classes, and do it yourself, or you can try some external libs for it @gaurang